# Manipulating React State from an Existing DOM Node

Tags: reactjs, dom, react-dom, virtual-dom

I'm currently using a, "Handsontable," wrapper for React (react-handsontable).

The main issue I've been having is being able to hook into a `<select>` field that was created by the wrapper to change my application state.

I need to hook into an input that's on the DOM (not the virtual DOM) and `onchange` change my component state.

How can I go about accomplishing this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered rendering the select as a React component itself with an `onChange` handler? Either way, what you could do is add a custom renderer where you add the `onchange` handler to that select element, and assign it to a bound method of your React component class. That way you'll be able to modify state with it without needing to do anything nasty like manipulating state from a DOM node.

Comment: Id really like to render the ```select``` as a react component but the wrapper turns it into a string ill have to look at what it would take to create a custom renderer to render a React component in the header of this wrapper ill do some research thank you ZekeDroid

Comment: Yeah you can always render it using `ReactDOM.render` and give it the `td` as the container. That's what we do in our projects and it works great!

Comment: but wouldn't it basically be a second react applications so it would have its own state?

Comment: in theory, yes, but you'll be attaching a bound change handler (bound to your "main" React component) so it won't have state of itself, just a handler that's referenced in your actual component.

Answer (score 0):

Using refs to bind the parent container to access the children and their event delegation

```
<div ref={ this.bindElementToInstance }>
  <DataTable
    tableData={ tableData }
    header={ OPTIONS[selectedTab].header }
   />
</div>
```

Bind the element

```
bindElementToInstance = (element) => {
  this.tableContainer = element;
}
```

use the change event propagation

```
componentDidMount() {
 this.tableContainer.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
   if (e.target.name === GRAIN_INPUT_NAME) {
     this.setState({
       selectedGrain: e.target.value,
     });
   }
 });
}
```

I'm now changing the state of my react application with some dark magic

Comment: yeah, this is what happens when you go aginst the grain of react and use a wrapper that touches the DOM directly.